# Why PyCharm wants project files to exclude from Windows Defender's Real Time Scanning?

Tags: pycharm, windows-defender

All of the sudden, PyCharm wants to configure Windows Defender to exclude project files from Windows Defender's Real Time Scanning. The reason for such configuration was to "improve performance". Why does this happen all of the sudden?

I have used PyCharm before on Windows Defender, but such a notification never came. Why does this happen? Can anyone explain in detail?

What files does the PyCharm wants to protect from Windows Defender?

NOTE : I use Windows Defender to secure my PC.

I've attached an pic of the notification that was displayed.

[PyCharm's "Configure Windows Defender" Notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75O2f.png)

Answer (score 0):

The warning was added few months ago https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-216072

Source code https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/platform-impl/src/com/intellij/diagnostic/WindowsDefenderChecker.java

Feel free to ignore it, it's just a suggestion to improve the performance.